# How to efficiently search for a value in DataFrame and put it into another DataFrame

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have two CSV files:

**File1**

```
id  text_feature  value
1   feature2      20
1   feature3      5
2   feature2      20
...
```

**File2**

```
id  feature2  feature3
1   1         1
2   1         0
...
```

Based on these files I want to get the following file (i.e. substitute 1's and 0's by `values`):

**File3**

```
id  feature2  feature3
1   20        5
2   20        0
...
```

This is how I try to solve the task, but it takes so long time (my CSV files have around 20,000 entries):

```
import pandas as pd

def find_value(df_data, df_row, column_name):
    value = 0
    for index, row in df_data.iterrows():
        f = row['feature'].replace(' ','')
        if row['id'] == df_row['id'] and f == column_name:
            value = row['volume']
            break
    return value

df_data = pd.read_csv("File1.csv")
df_textfeatures = pd.read_csv("File2.csv")

for index, row in df_textfeatures.iterrows():
    for column_name, column in df_textfeatures.transpose().iterrows():
        row[column_name] = find_value(df_data, row, column_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly pivot your `dataframe` called file1:

```
d = file1.pivot_table(index='id',columns='text_feature',values='value')
```

that returns:

```
text_feature  feature2  feature3
id                              
1                   20         5
2                   20       NaN
```

To get what you need, you can then fill `NaN` values with 0:

```
d.fillna(0)
```

This returns:

```
text_feature  feature2  feature3
id                              
1                   20         5
2                   20         0
```

EDIT:

You then have to reset the index to make the index set as columns:

```
d.reset_index()
```

which returns:

```
text_feature  id  feature2  feature3
0              1        20         5
1              2        20         0
```

Comment: I checked your solution, but it does not save `id` column in `d` DataFrame. Why?

Comment: Your solution is really cool. It does what I actually need. Just a small detail that I didn't clearly explain in my post: File2 does not contain all the `id` from File1. That's why I made searching in my solution. So, how can I filter out only those entries from `d`, which are mentioned in File2 (I do not need all entries from File1)?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos mmm that's another point I think. Please consider in asking a new question with modified input data.